# VITE.JS SSR Not Working with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-router, react-router-dom, vite

I been trying to create template with `Vite SSR` with `react-router-dom` for my requirements.
i know `Next JS` is better alternative for `Vite SSR`.

heare i have some configs that i made for this template.

#### Vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    ssr: {
        external: [
            'react-router-dom'
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@App": path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src"),
            "@Components": path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/Components"),
            "@Pages": path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/pages"),
            "@Styles": path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/Styles"),
            "@Public": path.resolve(process.cwd(), "public")
        },
    },
})
```

#### Src/App.tsx

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


function Application() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            HI
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default Application;
```

#### Console

[image]

#### How to Reproduce this template

```bash
yarn create vite
```

Select Others
Select ssr-react
Select typescript+swc

Replace src/App.tsx to upper file

Run

```bash
yarn dev
```

##### Tags

`vite` `vitejs` `vitejs ssr` `react` `react-router` `react-router-dom` `ssr` `js dom` `vite config`

I Expected to working React application with `react-router-dom`.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/Lomray-Software/vite-ssr-boost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Vite SSR + React Router Dom is working with `StaticRouter`

- I researched so much and i found this [blog](https://devpress.csdn.net/react/62f52ed37e6682346618a462.html) this is accidently worked but not satisfy me i made some changed on it.
- This is easily useable and alternative of `next.js ssr` rendering

#### Follow steps to replicate template

- Run in terminal

```
yarn create vite
```

- Select react
- Select typescript+swc
- Run this Command in terminal

```bash
yarn add compression cross-env sirv express react-router-dom
```

- Create Files and Folders this you see in this picture

> [image]

> ### Files
>
> #### Root/Server.js

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import { createServer as createViteServer } from "vite";

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const Port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const Base = process.env.BASE || "/";

const templateHtml = isProduction
    ? fs.readFileSync("./dist/client/index.html", "utf-8")
    : "";

const ssrManifest = isProduction
    ? await fs.readFile("./dist/client/ssr-manifest.json", "utf-8")
    : undefined;

const app = express();
let vite;

// ? Add vite or respective production middlewares
if (!isProduction) {
    vite = await createViteServer({
        server: { middlewareMode: true },
        appType: "custom",
    });

    app.use(vite.middlewares);
} else {
    const sirv = (await import("sirv")).default;
    const compression = (await import("compression")).default;
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(Base, sirv("./dist/client", {
        extensions: [],
        gzip: true,
    }));
}

app.use("*", async (req, res, next) => {

    // ! Favicon Fix
    if (req.originalUrl === "/favicon.ico") {
        return res.sendFile(path.resolve("./public/vite.svg"));
    }


    // ! SSR Render - Do not Edit if you don't know what heare whats going on
    let template, render;

    try {
        if (!isProduction) {
            template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./index.html"), "utf-8");
            template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(req.originalUrl, template);
            render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule("/src/entry-server.tsx")).render;
        } else {
            template = templateHtml;
            render = (await import("./dist/server/entry-server.js")).render;
        }

        const rendered = await render({ path: req.originalUrl }, ssrManifest);
        const html = template.replace(`<!--app-html-->`, rendered ?? '');

        res.status(200).setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html").end(html);
    } catch (error) {
        vite.ssrFixStacktrace(error);
        next(error);
    }
});

// ? Start http server
app.listen(Port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${Port}`);
});
```

> #### Root/src/entry-server.tsx

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";

import { Router } from "./router";

interface IRenderProps {
    path: string;
}

export const render = ({ path }: IRenderProps) => {
    return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={path}>
            <Router />
        </StaticRouter>
    );
};
```

> #### Root/src/entry-client.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import { Router } from "./router";

ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(
    document.getElementById("app") as HTMLElement,
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Router />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

> #### Root/src/router.tsx

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { Other } from "./pages/Other";
import { NotFound } from "./pages/NotFound";

export const Router = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/other" element={<Other />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};
```

> #### Root/package.json - Edit Scripts only

```json
{
    "scripts": {
         "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./server.js",
         "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
         "build:client": "vite build --outDir dist/client",
         "build:server": "vite build --ssr src/entry-server.tsx --outDir dist/server",
         "serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server.js"
    }
}
```

> #### Root/index.html - Required to Edit

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        <!--app-html-->
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/entry-client.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> #### Root/src/pages/Home.tsx - Optional Normal React Component

```
export const Home = () => {
    return <div>This is the Home Page</div>;
};
```

> #### Root/src/pages/Other.tsx - Optional Normal React Component

```
export const Other= () => {
    return <div>This is the Another Page</div>;
};
```

> #### Root/src/pages/NotFound.tsx - Optional Normal React Component

```
export const NotFound = () => {
    return <div>Not Found</div>;
};
```

- Run in terminal

```bash
yarn dev
```

### Outputs

> [image: Homepage]

> [image: Not Found OR 404 ERROR]

Comment: This Ans is Too much time consuming while first render